# How to get the right data?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have this ElasticSearch Query for ES ,version:2.2:

```json
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                     "term": {
                        "companyId": 3211002
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "hrId": 1005031
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "terms": {
                                    "manager": [
                                        1005031
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        {
                                            "exists": {
                                                "field": "manager"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "terms": {
                                                "manager": []
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must_not": {
                                        "exists": {
                                            "field": "manager"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match": "1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "status": [
                            "0"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must_not": {
                                        "exists": {
                                            "field": "approvals"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "nested": {
                                    "query": {
                                        "terms": {
                                            "approvals.approvalStatus": [
                                                1
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "path": "approvals"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match": "1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "createTime": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But,ES gives me back this:

```json
{
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "recruitment",
                "_type": "requirement",
                "_id": "501",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 501,
                    "companyId": 3211002,
                    "hrId": 1005031,
                    "formId": 501,
                    "requirementId": "Test0004",
                    "positionTitle": "招聘需求004",
                    "positionProperties": 1,
                    "requirementCount": 3,
                    "requirementType": 1,
                    "reportTo": 1004651,
                    "requirementTeam": 188384773,
                    "requirementStatus": 0,
                    "manager": [
                        1005031
                    ],
                    "status": 0,
                    "createTime": 1685350126881,
                    "hasAttachment": false
                },
                "sort": [
                    1685350126881
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "recruitment",
                "_type": "requirement",
                "_id": "498",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 498,
                    "companyId": 3211002,
                    "hrId": 1004483,
                    "formId": 498,
                    "requirementId": "Test0002",
                    "positionTitle": "审批测试1",
                    "positionProperties": 2,
                    "requirementCount": 2,
                    "requirementStatus": 0,
                    "status": 0,
                    "createTime": 1685346243403,
                    "hasAttachment": false,
                    "approvals": [
                        {
                            "approvalStatus": 1,
                            "nodes": [
                                {
                                    "approvers": [
                                        {
                                            "approverStatus": 3,
                                            "id": 1005031
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "nodeStatus": 3
                                },
                                {
                                    "approvers": [
                                        {
                                            "approverStatus": 1,
                                            "id": 1004789
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "approverStatus": 1,
                                            "id": 1004483
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "nodeStatus": 1
                                }
                            ],
                            "createTime": "2023-05-29T15:44:07+08:00",
                            "hrId": 1004483,
                            "id": 597
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "sort": [
                    1685346243403
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I don't understand why ID = 498 is returned.

My goal is to filter out id = 498, I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the nested query inside of a must_not, it should work:

```
GET test_hr/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "companyId": 3211002
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "hrId": 1005031
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "manager": [
                    1005031
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "manager"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "manager": []
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "manager"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "status": [
              "0"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": {
                    "nested": {
                      "path": "approvals",
                      "query": {
                        "exists": {
                          "field": "approvals"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": "1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "createTime": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

### test

```
PUT test_hr
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "approvals":{
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test_hr/_doc/501
{
  "id": 501,
  "companyId": 3211002,
  "hrId": 1005031,
  "formId": 501,
  "requirementId": "Test0004",
  "positionTitle": "招聘需求004",
  "positionProperties": 1,
  "requirementCount": 3,
  "requirementType": 1,
  "reportTo": 1004651,
  "requirementTeam": 188384773,
  "requirementStatus": 0,
  "manager": [
    1005031
  ],
  "status": 0,
  "createTime": 1685350126881,
  "hasAttachment": false
}

PUT test_hr/_doc/498
{
  "id": 498,
  "companyId": 3211002,
  "hrId": 1004483,
  "formId": 498,
  "requirementId": "Test0002",
  "positionTitle": "审批测试1",
  "positionProperties": 2,
  "requirementCount": 2,
  "requirementStatus": 0,
  "status": 0,
  "createTime": 1685346243403,
  "hasAttachment": false,
  "approvals": [
    {
      "approvalStatus": 1,
      "nodes": [
        {
          "approvers": [
            {
              "approverStatus": 3,
              "id": 1005031
            }
          ],
          "nodeStatus": 3
        },
        {
          "approvers": [
            {
              "approverStatus": 1,
              "id": 1004789
            },
            {
              "approverStatus": 1,
              "id": 1004483
            }
          ],
          "nodeStatus": 1
        }
      ],
      "createTime": "2023-05-29T15:44:07+08:00",
      "hrId": 1004483,
      "id": 597
    }
  ]
}
```

---

```
#not working
GET test_hr/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "approvals"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

#working
GET test_hr/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "approvals",
            "query": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "approvals"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help!I have encountered another issue: how do I use rangeQuery to search for the lower limit of salary ('salaryBottom') and the upper limit of salary ('salaryTop')? like salary  between 11 and 15

Comment: You're welcome, happy to hear it worked. Please ask another question and ping me. It'd be great if you can also give examples like you did for this question :)

Comment: Ok, here's the link to the new question：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76405037/elastic-search-rangequery

Comment: Val answered the question :)